# Convert string to double,

Tags: c#

I have a string array which contains 4 elements. Which looks like this.

[image]

How ever, when trying to do this:

```
Vector newVector = new Vector(
(float)Convert.ToDouble(words[1]),
(float)Convert.ToDouble(words[2]));
```

I get the following error:

> 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

And that is because it's because the value uses a '.' but if I manually change the array to use a ',' it works. 
How can I easiest replace all '.' with ','.

Comment: Use `String.Replace` or other regional setings where decimal separtor is `.`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `float` typecasting?

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll(words.Split(','), Double.Parse);`
This will convert your string array to a double array.
In fact I got this from another [SO][1] question. I hope this solves your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524682/fastest-way-to-convert-string-array-to-double-array

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
//(float)Convert.ToDouble(words[1]),
  (float)Convert.ToDouble(words[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Vector newVector = new Vector(
(float)Convert.ToDouble(words[1], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat),
(float)Convert.ToDouble(words[2], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat));
```